# CX usb3 2.5-hdd-case asm1051 wont spindown/detach on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb, hard-drive, spindown

bought this device

http://www.ebay.de/itm/281128589294?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649

it mount and unmount the partitions on the drive smart is also supported the only thing what does not work is detach/spin down

is it a hardware chipset problem or software problem?

```
uname -a

Linux lenovo-g555 3.2.0-56-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 09:20:45 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 5986:0148 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174c:5106 ASMedia Technology Inc. Transcend StoreJet 25M3

lsusb -vd 001:003

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174c:5106 ASMedia Technology Inc. Transcend StoreJet 25M3
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x174c ASMedia Technology Inc.
  idProduct          0x5106 Transcend StoreJet 25M3
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           2 
  iProduct                3 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0

udisks --detach /dev/sdb

Detach failed: Error detaching: helper exited with exit code 1: Detaching device /dev/sdb
USB device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1)
SYNCHRONIZE CACHE: FAILED: No such file or directory
(Continuing despite SYNCHRONIZE CACHE failure.)
STOP UNIT: FAILED: No such file or directory
```

if something is missing please let me know ...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same device and the same problem.

I can say that my WD Passport 2.5" 2TB external USB3 disk works fine in this regard though - it sleeps when not in use, and when the computer sleeps. So it seems to be a driver or chipset issue.

Can you try to boot a live CD (or USB image) of Ubuntu 14.04 alpha/beta and test if it works there? I tried using my case, and there was no change. *However*, there might be a firmware update for the ASM1051 chipset available which supports spindown modes. If you find such an update, please let us know!